# How to access one UIViewControllers properties from another UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have one single MainViewController which has of course it's one main UIView. I have this main view comprised of many different subviews.

Some of these subviews have their very own ViewController.

Lets say the *MAIN* view (whose delegate is primarily MainViewController) has a container which loads another UIView that uses a separate UIViewController- *SecondaryViewController* as the delegate for most it's actions.

This container view is of course loaded in *MainViewController* via

```
MyContainerViewController *myContainerController = 
         [[MyContainerViewController alloc] ...]; 
[self addSubView: myContainerController.view];
```

the controller for myContainerController.view though is *MyContainerViewController*. How inside this controller do I access MainViewController properties? Specifically I need to access MainViewController's - self.navigationController property to push a new ViewController? :)

Does this make any sense? I assume there's going to be casting of some sort involved since it seems I need to somehow retain a reference to MainViewController inside SecondaryViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to push a new ViewController from the SecondaryViewController in the MainViewController.
This screws up the design of the code. A child object will access its parents method to call a method. By other words: bad code.
Make a delegate call from the SecondaryViewController to the MainViewController that it state has changed. Then the MainViewController can decide to do with the call and the SecondaryViewController will not know anything about the implementation of the MainViewController.

So:
Make a protocol in SecondaryViewController.
Let the MainViewController be SecondaryViewController's delegate.
Implement the delegate method in MainViewController which pushes the new ViewController.

Comment: err I think this is the approach I want to do. I guess I need to read up on creating protocols and properly creating delegates for view controllers. Can't easily do it with Interface Builder it seems.

Comment: At least you can make the delegate an IBOutlet, this will make it easier to make the MainViewController the delegate of the SecondaryViewController (This is only relevant when the SecondaryViewController should exist when the MainViewController is loaded from its NIB)

Answer (score 0):

Expose the desired sub-view controllers as properties of the view controller that contains them.

Expose your root view controller(s) as properties of your app delegate, and synthesize them also.

When you want to access a different UIViewController, first obtain a reference to your appDelegate:

```
MyAppDelegate* myAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Then just use your chain of properties to get access to your desired view controller.

```
SubSubViewController* ssvc = myAppDelegate.rootViewController.subViewController.subSubViewController;
```

Some folks frown upon the use of the sharedApplication class method to obtain the reference to a delegate, but I've used it in multiple apps and not suffered for it (yet).  The alternative is to pipe your appDelegate through your hierarchy of viewControllers.

Comment: Sorry to say so, but this makes the SecondaryViewController know the implementation of the MainViewController, which actually is its parent. Bad code design.

Comment: Nope - MainViewController knows SecondaryViewController, but Secondary would not know Main.  (The references all point "downward").

Comment: Your using your delegate as an object. Your assuming your application delegate has variables of UIViewController kind. This is wrong because the UIApplicationDelegate is a protocol and has methods it is conform to. Not instance variables. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html. And when your using your delegate as object, as i aid before, you will have a "upward" reference.